# Puedo implementar un método que verifique la pertenencia de un voto a un usuario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Deseo validar si la pregunta seleccionada en el `index` corresponde al usuario logueado o no.

vote.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: votes
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  voteable_id   :integer
#  voteable_type :string
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#  user_id       :integer
#

class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  def  self.voted_by?(user, voteable)
    voteable.votes.find_by(user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

votes_controller.rb

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_voteable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @voteable.votes.create(user: current_user)
    redirect_to question_path(question), notice: "A successfully voted..."
  end

  def destroy
    @voteable.votes.where(user: current_user).take.try(:destroy)
     redirect_to question_path(question), notice: "Successfully removed vote..."
  end

  private

    def question
      @voteable.try(:question) || @voteable
    end

# Método agregado

    def vote_user?(question, current_user)
      vote_valid = true
      if (@voteable.user_id ==  current_user)
        vote_valid = false    
      end
    end
end
```

¿Está correcto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo optaría por poner el método en el modelo `Vote`:

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  def self.voted_by?(user, voteable)
    voteable.votes.find_by(user_id: user.id)
  end

  def belongs_to?(user)
    user_id = user.id
  end
end
```

Y para utilizarlo, basta con pasar un el usuario como parámetro, por ejemplo:

```
@vote = Vote.find(id_voto_a_comparar)
@vote.belongs_to?(current_user)
```